# How to Add a scroll bar to a JTabbedPane. Basically i have an admin panel which is attached further on a frame as a TAB(JTabbedPane)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtabbedpane

//here admin is a panel located on a frame as 2nd TAB on which i want to add a Scroll bar.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
public class admin extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 JLabel lb;
 Image image;
 JScrollPane js;
 public admin()   //admin panel is invoked by a frame. 
 {

    setBackground(Color.white);

    add(new admsign()); // admsign is another panel located on admin which is a simple form. 


// if you want me to post the code for admsign() then tell me.




 }
}
```

// i think it is unnecessary.

Comment: I already got my answer with the help of user PEESKILLET. :D 
I think this was enough for describing my problem.

Comment: seemed like a pretty clear-cut question to me... ! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "How to Add a scroll bar to a JTabbedPane. Basically i have an admin panel which is attached further on a frame as a TAB(JTabbedPane)"

Basically, you *don't*. You wrap the `JScollPane` around the `JPanel` that is added to the `JTabbedPane`

```
JTabbedPane tabbed = new JTabbedPane();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

tabbed.add(new JScrollPane(panel1), "Panel 1");
tabbed.add(new JScrollPane(panel2), "Panel 2");
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestTabbedScroll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    box.add(new JLabel("Hello, StackOverflow!"));
                }
                panel.add(box);
                panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

                JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
                scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
                tab.add(scroll, "Panel 1");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                        null, tab, "Test Tabbed", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```